# Determining the location of a JSON parse error

Tags: json, parsing, numbers, line

I am creating a web application that allows a user to load data in JSON format.  I am currently using the following function to read JSON files that I have saved on my local disk:

```
function retrieveJSON(url, callback)
{
  // this is needed because FireFox tries to parse files as XML
  $.ajaxSetup({ mimeType: "text/plain" });

  // send out an AJAX request and return the result
  $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
    console.log("Data acquired successfully");
    callback(response);
  }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Error...\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
  });
}
```

This works perfectly for well-formed JSON data.  However, for malformed data, the console log displays the following:

```
Error...
parsererror
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

This is almost entirely unhelpful because it does not tell me what the unexpected character is or what line number it can be found on.  I could use a JSON validator to correct the file on my local disk, but this is not an option when the page is loading files from remote URLs on the web.

How can I obtain the location of any error?  I would like to obtain the token if possible, but I need to obtain the line number at minimum.  There is a project requirement to display an excerpt of the JSON code to the user and highlight the line where any error occurred.

I am currently using jQuery, but jQuery is not a project requirement, so if another API or JSON parser provides this functionality, I could use that instead.

Comment: Well, there were no responses before the deadline, which is discouraging. Out of desperation I discovered that eval() will tell you the line number, so I used that as a placeholder. Unfortunately, eval() does not have the same safeguards as a JSON parser.

But the project leader doesn't care about that, so the placeholder has become the implementation -- which is a problem as we're loading JSON from external sources. So now the page has a security vulnerability, I've been dinged for taking too long to solve a "simple problem", and I've been chided about going off task on "irrelevant concerns".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, life with deadlines is never easy :).

This might help you out, after couple of hours googling around, I've found [jsonlint](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint) on Git Hub. It looks promising, it includes a [shell script](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint/blob/master/lib/cli.js) that could be used on server side, and there is a [browser JavaScript](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint/blob/master/lib/jsonlint.js) version  of it that seems to be exactly what you were looking for.

Hope that this will help You.

Comment: That does look promising.  Thanks!  I'm not sure when I might be able to swap this code for the code currently being used, but I will definitely check it out at my first opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

i agree that life with deadlines is hard.
i'm incredibly happy that i don't have to live with deadlines, i'm my own boss.

so in search of a better solution to this problem, i came up with the following :

```
...
        readConfig : function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : 'config.json',
                success : function (data, ts, xhr) {
                    var d = JSON.parse(data);
                },
                error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    if (typeof thrownError.message=='string') {
                        // ./config.json contains invalid data.
                        var 
                        text = xhr.responseText,
                        pos = parseInt(thrownError.message.match(/position (\d+)/)[1]),
                        html = text.substr(0,pos)+'<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">__'+text.substr(pos,1)+'__</span>'+text.substr(pos+1, text.length-pos-1);
                        cm.install.displayErrorMsg('Could not read ./config.json :(<br/>'+thrownError+'<br/>'+html);
                    } else {
                        cm.install.displayErrorMsg('Error retrieving ./config.json<br/>HTTP error code : '+xhr.status);
                    };
                }
            });
        },
...
```